# Unable to connect to SQL Server azure through ssms

Tags: authentication, ssms, azure-sql-database

I am new babie to Azure, recently I have created an Azure account and I am looking to create data schema for my project. I have created a SQL database and SQL Server. I am trying to connect through SSMS. Unfortunately I am stuck with "Cannot connect to the server" and "login failed for User".

Probably my password might be wrong or the server is not up. How can check my password (SQL Server authenciation) of SQL Server and how to check if my server is running?

P.S : I didn't create any VM

[image: Azure All resource page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also make sure your IP is in the list of IPs allowed to access the DB. Setup firewall rules using instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-firewall-configure/)

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I check if my SQL server in Azure is running?**

Open command prompt, run `ping <your server name here>`.
If this resolves to an IP address your server is online and running.

**How can I check password for my SQL Server?**

When you navigate to the server in the Azure portal, there should be a property under the Essentials tab called 'server admin'. Make sure this is the same login you use in SSMS.

If you can't remember your password, you can always reset it in the Azure portal: 
[image: Portal Reset password screenshot]